# Calling a Web Service in Android

Tags: android

I am currently working on an application in android where I need to call the Web Service. I am working in Android and I don't have an idea about how to call a web Service in Android.

So, can anybody please help me out in how to call a Web Service in Android Programming.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 1):

We use [Ksoap2](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) WS-Stack implementation, suitable for constrained devices such a mobile phone. You can not use it directly on Android. However there is a port with some small tweaks so it can work. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

Comment: This appears to be the only method. I researched this pretty thoroughly myself. Just a shame that Ksoap2 is TERRIBLE for any web service that expects you to generate proxy classes from a WSDL

Comment: You are right. I am not great fan of Ksoap2 myself, but as u stated this is for the time being the only available approach (other than building your self WS-Stack)