# python mysql insert the received message from android

Tags: python, mysql

How to insert the received message from android to python in mySQL?

In other words I'm opening socket between android and python and anything I enter in android it send to my python then I want this thing whatever string or it to be insert to python !!

I know about the insert method and it works fine with me but I want to do this method using the received message. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to consider is setting up a [Python-based Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415192/best-way-to-create-a-simple-python-web-service).  [Call the Web service from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649523/calling-a-web-service-in-android) and have the Web service do your database INSERTs for you.

Be sure to implement sufficient measures in your Web service to ensure that not-just-any query is allowed to be performed simply by passing it into your Web service.  Implement a query sanitizer, or similar.  [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/) is a fairly heavy-weight ORM framework (implemented in Python), but it does have its own query sanitizer.